# What is the official noun of "to distinguish"?

Tags: nouns

I checked Wiktionary [1] but it does not reference to a noun for **to distinguish**.

[1] https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinguish

Comment: The noun "[distinction](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinction#English)" is listed as a related term. Is that not what you want? What meaning do you want this noun to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiktionary lists  also ***[distinction](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinction)*** as:

> ***That which distinguishes***; a single occurrence of a determining factor or feature, the fact of being divided; separation, discrimination.

Comment: sumelic addresses this genref question correctly, in a 'comment'.